# sampler2DRect vs samplerRect

Tags: shader, opengl-3

As titled, I wish to know the difference between sampler2DRect and samplerRect

I already googled, but I couldnt find anything clear and precise. 
From what I found, it looks to me like samplerRect is somehow a relict of the past on the NV cards, that was standardized later as sampler2DRect, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're essentially correct; there's both an Nvidia extension and some ARB history involved here.

In the earliest version of [ARB_texture_rectangle](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_rectangle.txt), the specification referred to samplerRect and samplerRectShadow. You can see that this was changed in early 2005.

I see references to `samplerRect` working on Nvidia cards circa 2005, and it's noteworthy that [NV_texture_rectangle](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/texture_rectangle.txt) is nearly identical to ARB_texture_rectangle except for not specifying the interactions with GLSL. So, it appears that Nvidia had a working implementation of the ARB extension quickly, based on an early draft of that extension, because they had a very similar vendor-specific extension shipping.

As of February 2005, ARB_texture_rectangle specified `sampler2DRect`, so `samplerRect` is (as you say) a relic of that interval between March 2004 and February 2005.